# VIM - Cursor position after paste differs based on count prefix

Tags: vim

The cursor position for `p` changes if I am doing it repeatedly or if I am using count.

Consider this text:

```
hello
~
~
```

With the cursor on the word, I do `Y` and do manually `p` 4 times, the cursor is on the last line

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello <- cursor is here
```

However, if do `Y4p` on the first line, the cursor is on the second line

```
hello
hello <- cursor is here
hello
hello
hello
```

Is this by design? Shouldn't the functionality be the exact same for doing manually and using count? BTW, it works as expected for `P`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `p` and `P` when pasting whole lines is to place the cursor at the beginning of the contents that were just pasted. In each case, that is what is happening: when you hit `p` 4 times, you're making the cursor move to the beginning of the newly pasted line each time; when you hit `4p`, the cursor is at the beginning of the pasted block.

I agree it might not be the nicest behaviour if you're going to use these commands in a scripted way, but it's not a bug.

You'll notice the opposite behaviour if you paste a partial line: `p` and `P` leave the cursor at the end of the newly pasted text, which means here that 4x`p` and `4p` behave the same, but 4x`P` and `4P` really don't! (They don't even produce the same results, let alone leave the cursor in the same place...)

In any case, all of these are the results of reasonable choices of where you will *usually* want your cursor after a paste operation.